# Modify large JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON for mobile contacts data in this format:

```
post_data = [
    {
        "contact_first_name": "First Name",
        "contact_last_name": "Last Name",
        "contact_no": "98 9898 9999",
        "is_registered_user": False
    },
    {
        "contact_first_name": "First Name",
        "contact_last_name": "Last Name",
        "contact_no": "1 987 876 6545",
        "is_registered_user": False
    },
    {
        "contact_first_name": "First Name",
        "contact_last_name": "Last Name",
        "contact_no": "44 674 437878 4343",
        "is_registered_user": False
    }
]
```

I want to remove all the white spaces from contact_no key, is there any best solution in python to iterate and remove white spaces if we have more than 10000 contacts in a json.

Here is my code in python but i think this is not good solution for large dataset:

```
final_json = []
for index, json_data in enumerate(post_data):
    for i in json_data["contact_no"]:
        final_json.append(i) if i!=' ' else i
    formated_contact = ''.join(final_json)
    post_data[index]["contact"] = formated_contact
print post_data
```

Comment: why down votes?

Comment: your main problem would be storing your large JSON in memory, not modifying it

Comment: @AzatIbrakov a list of 10000 of such small dicts is really not likely to cause a memory issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for data in post_data:
    data['contact_no'] = data['contact_no'].replace(' ', '')


print(post_data)
# [{'contact_first_name': 'First Name', 'contact_last_name': 'Last Name', 'contact_no': '9898989999', 'is_registered_user': False}, {'contact_first_name': 'First Name', 'contact_last_name': 'Last Name', 'contact_no': '19878766545', 'is_registered_user': False}, {'contact_first_name': 'First Name', 'contact_last_name': 'Last Name', 'contact_no': '446744378784343', 'is_registered_user': False}]
```